# Proof using Bayes' formula with three random variables

Tags: probability, proof-writing, bayes-theorem

I'm working on the following proof:

I have three random variables, where $X\in\{0,1\}, Z\in\{0,1\}$, and $Y$ is a continuous random variable. I have two assumptions:
$$P(X=1\mid Y=\bar{y})>P(X=1\mid Y=y') \text{ for some } \bar{y}>y'$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$P(Z=1\mid X=1)>P(Z=1\mid X=0)$$

My question is, are the assumptions above enough to prove that $P(Z=1\mid Y=\bar{y}) > P(Z=1\mid Y=y')?$ I've been trying to prove using Bayes' formula, but I'm getting nowhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Where you wrote "$X=\{0,1\}$" did you mean $X\in\{0,1\}$?

Comment: ok, I see that that was the case. I've corrected the notation.